# How do I unit test the event raised by class under test?

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I have below class which is responsible for raising the event based on some business conditions.

```cs
public class EventRaiserClass : IEventRaiserClass 
{
    public event EventHandler SendEventToClient;

    public void RaiseEventForClient()
    {
        SendEventToClient?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

Here is my Client class

```cs
public class Client :IClient
{
    EventRaiserClass _eventRaiser;
    public Client(EventRaiserClass eventraiser)
    {
        _eventRaise = eventraise;
        _iotGwStatus.SendEventToClient += OnSendEventToClient;
    }

    private async void OnSendEventToClient(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await SendEventToClient();
    }

    public async Task SendEventToClient()
    {
        //do some operation
    }
}
```

`EventRaiserClass` is injected to below class which is responsible for processing some orders

```cs
public class ProcessRequest: IProcessRequest
{
    IEventRaiserClass _evntRaiser;
    public ProcessRequest(IEventRaiserClass evntRaiser)
    {
        _evntRaiser = evntRaiser;
    }

    public void Process(JObject json)
    {
        _evntRaiser.RaiseEventForClient(); 
    }
}
```

Now, How do I unit test above `Process` method? How do I make sure the event is raised when `process` method is called?

Comment: As far as I can tell, your `Client` class is irrelevant to this question? It's not referenced anywhere.

Answer (score 7):

As far as I can tell, the `Client` class is irrelevant to this question? You just want to test the calling `ProcessRequest.Process` calls `EventRaiserClass.RaiseEventForClient`.

A simple way, without any mocks, using the `EventRaiserClass`:

```
var eventRaiser = new EventRaiserClass();
bool eventRaised = false;
eventRaiser.SendEventToClient += (o, e) => eventRaised = true;

var processRequest = new ProcessRequest(eventRaiser);
processRequest.Process(someJObject);

Assert.True(eventRaised);
```

You can go further, and test that the event is raised exactly once:

```
// Arrange
var eventRaiser = new EventRaiserClass();
int eventRaisedCount = 0;
eventRaiser.SendEventToClient += (o, e) => eventRaisedCount++;

var processRequest = new ProcessRequest(eventRaiser);

// Act
processRequest.Process(someJObject);

// Assert
Assert.Equal(1, eventRaisedCount);
```

If you don't want to rely on `EventRaiserClass` and you're using a mocking framework, you can do something like this (I'm using [Moq](https://github.com/moq/moq4) in this example):

```
// Arrange
var eventRaiser = Mock<IEventRaiser>();
var processRequest = new ProcessRequest(eventRaiser.Object);

// Act
processRequest.Process(someJObject);

// Assert
eventRaiser.Verify(x => x.RaiseEventForClient());
```

The same using [NSubstitute](https://nsubstitute.github.io/help/getting-started/):

```
// Arrange
var eventRaiser = Substitute.For<IEventRaiser>();
var processRequest = new ProcessRequest(eventRaiser);

// Act
processRequest.Process(someJObject);

// Assert
eventRaiser.Received().RaiseEventForClient();
```

---

As a separate note, think a bit about how you name your classes. Most coding standards say that classes should be named using a *noun* or *noun phrase*, and shouldn't end with "Class".

So `Client` is OK, but `EventRaiserClass` ends with `Class`. Consider something like `EventRaiser`.

`ProcessRequest` isn't a noun or noun phrase -- it sounds like an instruction ("process this request"), which is typically how you'd name a method, not a class. Consider something like `RequestProcessor`, which is an object which processes requests.

Comment: Regarding a naming convention, yes I agree. I just modified my production code to simplify the question. Great, I am using NSubstitute  for mocking. How can I change it to NSubstitute?

Comment: Cool, added a section for NSubstitute.

Comment: Great!  You are a champion. Let me do quick testing and mark the answer.

Comment: (I wrote the NSubstitute section from the docs - I don't use it myself. If it doesn't work, I'll fix it)

Comment: sure, let me check it. In addition, I have one question related to passing "someJObject", in my case its a "JObject" - what is the best practise to pass this json in unit tests? do I have store "sample" json in some folder and refer using helper methods?

Comment: Personally, I'd store the sample json as a string straight in my test fixture class (or in a helper class in the test project, if it's used in more than one test fixture). Try not to make it too large - it's much better to have lots of small snippets of json for different tests, if possible, than to have one big snippet which is used in lots of different tests

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201192/discussion-between-kudlatiger-and-canton7).

Answer (score 1):

You may also want to check the thrown event with regard to *sender* and *eventArgs*.
If you don't want to write three test methods to test the entire event raising procedure, then [Nuclear.Test](https://mikelimasierra.net/index.php/software-projects/nuclear-test-platform/) is for you.

```cs
[TestMethod]
void TestProcessRaisesEvent() {

    // arrange
    var eventRaiser = new EventRaiserClass();
    var processRequest = new ProcessRequest(eventRaiser);
    var json = default(JObject); // create your json
    Action action = () => processRequest.Process(json);

    // act / assert
    Test.If.RaisesEvent(eventRaiser, "SendEventToClient", action, out Object sender, out EventArgs e);
    Test.If.ReferencesEqual(eventRaiser, sender);
    Test.If.ValuesEqual(e, EventArgs.Empty);

}
```

You should consider testing `EventRaiserClass` and `ProcessRequest` separately however.

```cs
[TestMethod]
void TestEventRaiserRaisesEvent() {

    // arrange
    var eventRaiser = new EventRaiserClass();
    Action action = () => eventRaiser.RaiseEventForClient();

    // act / assert
    Test.If.RaisesEvent(eventRaiser, "SendEventToClient", action, out Object sender, out EventArgs e);
    Test.If.ReferencesEqual(eventRaiser, sender);
    Test.If.ValuesEqual(e, EventArgs.Empty);

}

[TestMethod]
void TestProcessRaisesEvent() {

    // arrange
    var eventRaiser = new EventRaiserClass();
    var processRequest = new ProcessRequest(eventRaiser);
    var json = default(JObject); // create your json
    Action action = () => processRequest.Process(json);

    // act / assert
    Test.If.RaisesEvent(eventRaiser, "SendEventToClient", action, out Object sender, out EventArgs e);

}
```